# Get portion image from camera with Opencv

Tags: opencv, camera

I want to get portion image from camera. I have this code. This code is giving me rectangle on camera. I need to get rectangle include image.

```
 for(int i=0;i<(detectRect_face ? detectRect_face->total:0); i++ )
    {
        CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(detectRect_face, i); 
        CvPoint pt1 = { r->x+20, r->y+20 }; 
        CvPoint pt2 = { r->x + r->width-20, r->y + r->height-10 }; 
        cvRectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1,8, 0); 

         //I need to write here a method to get this rectangle include image.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cvSetImageROI and cvCopy methods to crop image.

```
IplImage *dst = // Prepare partition size image.
cvSetImageROI(frame, r);
cvCopy(frame, dst);
cvResetImageROI(frame);
```